# How can I package a boilerplate in to a NPM library?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have created a boiler plate which has server/client folders. I want to make a wrapper NPM library which copies this boiler, verbatim, to their computer.

Is there a way to package the source code into a NPM library as something that can easily be copied onto their computer? Or would it be easier to just make the wrapper library copy it from git?

Comment: Are you saying something along the lines of `yeoman` ? in other case if you want that as executable, put that in `bin` folder inside the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put anything in the `npm` package and it will be installed with `npm install` - unless it's in `.npmignore` on `.gitignore`. It will be installed in `node_modules` directory of the current project or globally if you use `npm install module-name -g`

If you have a `client` and `server` directory in your module then it will be installed in `node_modules/module-name/client` and `node_modules/module-name/server`.

Comment: @maxple that will be `node_modules/module-name/client` and `node_modules/module-name/server` - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best example to follow when creating a boilerplate is probably [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). It is structured as a set of npm packages all bundled up in a lerna monorepo. It is extremely easy to use and its structure has been well thought out, making it a great example to build from.